# RxJs and Angular, i need read two params from route and i want to use pipeable operators

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Given an Angular route, i need to read two parameters from the router in sequence.
Actually my code have nested subscription, but i don't like them so much

```
  this.route.parent.parent.params.subscribe(params => { 
      //read 'params'
      this.route.parent.parent.data.subscribe(anotherParams => {
         //read 'anotherParams' and do some thing with 'params'
       })
   })
```

I want to use rxjs operators for write 'subscribe' once, and inside of it give the access to both params.

Something like this:

```
 this.route.parent.parent.params.pipe( //some operators )
 .subscribe ( params, anotherParams => {
    'params' and 'anotherParams" readable inside that
  })
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53419090/3001761, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mergeMap`, `concatMap`, or `switchMap` to subscribe to another inner observable for you.

Here's an example using switchMap:

```js
this.route.parent.parent.params.pipe(
  switchMap(params => this.route.parent.parent.data.pipe(
    map(otherParams => ({params , otherParams }))
  ))
).subscribe(({params, otherParams}) => {
  // 'params' and 'anotherParams" readable inside that
});
```