# Merge two observables to get the value of two different Dto

Tags: rxjs, angular11

I have two `observables`, each one you get the value of a `Dto`:

```
this.about.aboutHeInfo().subscribe((heInfo: HemDto) => {
        this.uiUtils.openDialogResizable({
          hem: heInfo
        }, true, AboutComponent).subscribe();
      });

this.about.aboutPeInfo().subscribe((peInfo: PeoDto) => {
        this.uiUtils.openDialogResizable({
          peo: peInfo
        }, true, AboutComponent).subscribe();
      });
```

The problem is that when creating both observables two screens are opened because each function creates an apenDialog, how can I merge the two observables and open a single dialog box?

This is the merge I am testing:

```
const ob1 = this.about.aboutInfo().subscribe((heInfo: HemDto) => {
        this.heInfo= back;
      });

      const ob2 = this.about.aboutQoInfo().subscribe((peInfo: PeoDto) => {
          this.peInfo= people;
        });

forkJoin([ob1, ob2]).subscribe(() => {
        this.uiUtils.openDialogResizable({
          back: this.heInfo,
          people: this.peInfo
        }, true, AboutComponent).subscribe();
      });
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419090/merge-two-observables-single-output/53419306#53419306

Comment: I have already tried with ``zip`` but in this case I can't replicate it for both Dto and it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try using `merge` http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html

Comment: I have tried with ``merge``, ``combineLatest`` and ``forkJoin`` but I can't replicate it with any of them to get the information from both ``Dto``. I don't know if you have to use others as it is ``Angular 11``. Do you know how to do it in this case?

Comment: Can you post the code you tried in code? (add it to the question itself so we can help)

Comment: I attach the last one that I have tried with ``forkJoin``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use subscribe before `merge` function, `merge` take observable not what `subscribe` returns

Example

```js
const ob1 = this.about.aboutInfo()

const ob2 = this.about.aboutQoInfo()

forkJoin([ob1, ob2]).subscribe(([dto1, dto2]) => {
  ...
});
```